# How to cut bytes into separate pieces from socket

Tags: python, sockets, pygame

Ok so the title COULD be worded better, but here is the issue

I'm sending data REALLY quickly to a socket, and I need each piece of info sent to be separate

For example:

```
import pickle
#Sending side
while True:
     data = pickle.dumps((listelement1, listelement2, listelement3)) #All list elements may change value
     conn.send(data)


import pickle
#Revieving side
while True:
     dataget = conn.recv(1024)
     data_arr = pickle.loads(dataget)
     print(data_arr)
```

This of course isn't the actual code but my best example of it. I'm trying to make sure "dataget" is ALWAYS a whole "data" without accidentally truncating or cutting the front of the data off, how would I do that?

Comment: Are you sending more than 1024 bytes? You may need to loop `conn.recv()` until bytes received is zero.

Comment: @Mike67 - `recv(1024)` can return anything from 0 (meaning the socket has been closed) to 1024  bytes. Questioner needs to handle all read sizes in that range.

Comment: Use UDP. Have a look [here](https://pymotw.com/2/socket/udp.html)

Comment: I believe what you're asking about is known as message framing.  As Pynchia mentions, with UDP you get message framing "for free" (albeit with a number of downsides, chiefly the lack of reliable message delivery).  TCP is stream-based, OTOH, so to send your messages over TCP you need some way to let the receiver know where each message ends and the next one begins.  Prepending a fixed-size byte-count field to each message is one common way to do that; the receiver can then read the byte-count and then read the next N bytes to get the message's payload-data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic problem is that you need some way to demark messages within the TCP byte stream. This gets complicated fast. Pickled streams know their own size and if all you plan to do is pass pickled stuff back and forth, you can use that knowledge. Assuming you stick with blocking I/O, on the sending side its easy, just pickle and send, but use `s.sendall()` to make sure it really goes. `send()` may send less than you ask for and you have to check its return and keep sending. sendall does that for you.

The receive side is more complicated. `pickle.loads` requires you to load the byte string first (and how would you know how long it is?) and doesn't tell you how much of the stream it consumes. `pickle.Unpickler` does what you want, but uses a file object, not a socket. If you keep to blocking sockets, you can use `socket.makefile()` to create a file object for the socket and use that with the unpickler.

Here is a working example

```
import sys
import socket
import pickle

PORT = 8722

def client():
    s = socket.socket()
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    s.connect(('localhost', PORT))
    f = s.makefile(mode='wb')
    pickle.dump(["list 1", 1,2,3], f)
    pickle.dump(["list 2", 4, 5, 6], f)
    pickle.dump(["list 3", 7, 8, 9], f)
    f.close()
    s.close()

def server():
    s = socket.socket()
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    s.bind(('localhost', PORT))
    s.listen(1)
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    f = conn.makefile(mode='rb')
    unpkl = pickle.Unpickler(f)
    try:
        while True:
            obj = unpkl.load()
            print(obj)
    except EOFError:
        print('done')

try:
    if sys.argv[1] == "client":
        client()
    elif sys.argv[1] == "server":
        server()
    else:
        raise IndexError()
except IndexError:
    print("test.py client|server")
    exit(1)
```

Alternately, you can implement some method of delimiting each pickle buffer. Perhaps a small header written via `struct` that contains a size. Then its a two step process: read the header, then use that size to read the data. You can even step it up and use some other method like an HTTP rpc, or zeromq, etc...

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly for client to server, but how would I do server to client communication?

Comment: makefile works with blocking sockets. You have two way communications on the socket itself, but the client will need a new thread to do the receive.